# I have a date_time field in Dynamo-db table. How can I query only the entries between two specific timedates?

Tags: python, dynamodb-queries

I'm using boto3. The table name is exapmle_table. I want to get only specific hour entries according to the 
date_time field.

So far I've tried this without a success:

```
def read_from_dynamodb():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    one_hour_ago = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    now = timestamp = now.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
    now = int(now)
    one_hour_ago = one_hour_ago.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
    one_hour_ago = int (one_hour_ago)

    dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", aws_access_key_id=RnD_Credentials.aws_access_key_id,
                              aws_secret_access_key=RnD_Credentials.aws_secret_access_key,
                              region_name=RnD_Credentials.region
                              )
    example_table = dynamodb.Table('example_table')

    response = example_table.query(
        IndexName='date_time',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('date_time').between(one_hour_ago, now)
    )
    return response
```

I'm getting the error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: The table does not have the specified index: date_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries that rely on ranges - including `between` -  need the attribute (in your case `date_time`) to be a sort key in an index (primary or otherwise), and you'll also need to supply the partition key as part of the `KeyConditionExpression`. You can't query the entire table by sort key unless all items in the table have the same partition key.

If `date_time` is an attribute outside of the primary key you can add a GSI where `date_time` is the sort key but you'll still need to supply a partition key too.

Another idea if you're writing the data yourself is to create a new attribute with the start time of the hour for that item's `date_time` i.e. quantize it, then create a GSI hash key on that new hour attribute. Then you can query that specific hour rather than look for ranges. If you're working with existing data you could scan and refactor your table to add this attribute - not ideal but might be a solution depending on the size of the table and your use case.

If you're really stuck you could also `scan` and filter the table instead of `query`, but that is far less efficient as it will require reading every item every time you execute it.